# How to open two omxplayer instances

Tags: python, video

I need to open two omxplayer instances in raspberry pi and I'm using following code in python

```
command1='omxplayer', '--win', '0 0 1920 880', '-o', 'hdmi', '-d', '--layer', '5', 'DD.mp4'
command2='omxplayer', '--win', '0 880 1920 1080', '-o', 'hdmi', '-d', '--layer', '6','CC.mp4'

sp.Popen(command1)

sp.Popen(command2)
```

currently I'm using two video files and none of them are HD videos.
These two commands are working fine when I execute one at a time. But when I execute my python code or when I execute these commands in two ssh connections both videos are frozen. Somehow I need to play two video files in two omxplayers. I can't figure this out please help. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running those two commands in parallel outside of a Python program, directly on the console?  Just to rule out that it might be generally impossible to have two `omxplayer` running at the same time.

Comment: Yes I execute both in two different command lines, when I execute the command1 in command line it played nicely but when I execute command2 in other command line (ssh connections, PuTTY) both players frozen.

Answer (score 0):

```
command1='omxplayer', '--win', '0 0 1920 880', '-o', 'hdmi', '--layer', '5', 'DD.mp4'
command2='omxplayer', '--win', '0 880 1920 1080', '-o', 'hdmi', '--layer', '6','CC.mp4'

sp.Popen(command1)
sp.Popen(command2)
```

This is the code, the problem was using "-d" as a option in omxplayer.